# How to set multiple option for PDListBox in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox library to set the Values in PDF.

code block through I am trying to set values in ListBox

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    app.test();
}
public void test(){
    try {
        InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/2.pdf");
        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(resource);
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        PDListBox listBox = (PDListBox) acroForm.getField("multiple_listbox");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("option 2", "option 1");
        System.out.println("Set value in listBox: " + list);
        listBox.setValue(list);
        System.out.println("Get Value from list box: " + listBox.getValue());
        pdfDocument.save("pdfupdate.pdf");
        pdfDocument.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in result it shows only first value is selected from `List<String>` in PDF.
check result here:

[image]

How can I set multiple value selected in PDF?
PDFBox version : 2.0.6
Source pdf : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cbicbuwu0kjwlq/2.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Bad news: the source code has "// TODO: support highlighting multiple items if multiselect is set", i.e. it isn't implemented yet. Workaround if the generated PDFs are used in Adobe Reader only: call `acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true)`.

Comment: Good news: I'm working on the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3828

Comment: You can test with a snapshot: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.7-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: thanks @TilmanHausherr .
just let me know once issue solved.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: still not working.
Can you show me a working demo example?

Comment: I used your code from the question. When using the snapshot ( https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.7-SNAPSHOT/ ) , use a jar from the bottom, not from the top (number 85 or higher); and make sure that the 2.0.6 jar is not in the class path. Maybe create a separate project just to be sure.

Comment: Great!!! Its working. Thank you @TilmanHausherr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in PDFBox up to 2.0.6, and has been fixed in issue [PDFBOX-3828](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3828). The fix will be in version 2.0.7, expected to be released in late summer / fall 2017. For those who can't wait, get a [snapshot version](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.7-SNAPSHOT/) here (at the bottom of that web page).

Comment: Can you tell me exact released date of PDFBox version 2.0.7?

Comment: No I can't. Based on the past ( https://archive.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/ ), releases have been coming every 2-4 months. Please understand that we're a small team who do this in our spare time after work. Some of us have families, become ill, go on vacation, etc. Doing a release is more than just copy some jar files. If you don't want to use a snapshot, then take the source code of 2.0.6, make the change (see link from the issue), and rebuild.  P.S. please click the green checkmark to confirm that the answer is correct.